# Accurate location tracking using GPS and accelerometers in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, location

I'm looking for articles and/or algorithms on location tracking (and distance measuring) using the GPS on an iPhone, and in particular how to improve accuracy using the accelerometers. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use coreLocation for the first part.

Check out Apple's sample code [LocateMe](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LocateMe/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007801)

Comment: Thanks. I already have a basic algorithm up and running, that use core location. It works reasonably well, by just sampling the location at regular intervals and "connecting the dots". However, over large distances it becomes inaccurate because it cuts corners, and the GPS accuracy is poor in some areas. I'm looking for ways to improve on the basic algorithm.